# Windows Phone 7 Page Navigation and Data Retrieving

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm pretty new at this and not sure what the code should look like. I would like to do the following:

I want to code an application that will navigate to the 'settings page' of the windows phone  device and then "read"/ retrieve the data that displays under the 'Theme page'?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the MSDN site for that exact same thing, and found it a little lacking.

Basically what you want to use is the IsolatedStorageSettings object.  It's essentially a Dictionary that you can access in any page.

Here is the blog I found the most useful (it has simple examples that are free of extraneous stuff):

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/